# Docker IdentityServer 4 - 500 Server Error on Login

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, identityserver4

I am attempting to login to a Docker angular app using Identity Server for Authentication. Once I enter my credentials for on Identity Server, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

When I run this application locally (non-Docker) I am able to login with ID Server and return to the Angular App without seeing any errors. Which makes me think there must be something wrong with my ID Server Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet AS build-env  
ARG source  
RUN echo "source: $source"  
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

#Copy everything else & build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity.dll"]
```

Can anyone tell me why I am seeing a `500 Internal Server Error` in Docker, and what I can do to resolve this issue?

Much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Without logging or additional information it would be guessing.

Comment: Thanks @Ruard van Elburg. What information should I include? And how can I display the logging?

Comment: First make sure log is enabled on identityserver (ref: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html) and then copy the log output here